# How to detect XPath represent a leaf node or node set?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have below xml sample file and I'm going to get data using XPath (XPath is given randomly and can not identify whether the XPath represent leaf node or node set).

example of leaf node xpath:- /OrderResponse/OrderLine[2]/LineItem/ID

example of node set xpath:- /OrderResponse/OrderLine

Is there a way to detect xpath represent a leaf element or node set using java?

```
<OrderResponse>
    <ID>79858</ID>
    <IssueDate>2011-05-04</IssueDate>
    <OrderLine>
        <LineItem>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <SalesOrderID>1</SalesOrderID>
            <Note>tCP</Note>
            <LineStatusCode>1</LineStatusCode>
            <Quantity unitCode="PCE">1.0</Quantity>
        </LineItem>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
        <LineItem>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <SalesOrderID>2</SalesOrderID>
            <LineStatusCode>2</LineStatusCode>
            <Quantity unitCode="PCE">2.0</Quantity>
        </LineItem>
    </OrderLine>
</OrderResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those XPaths select node sets, but it's clear from your question that by "node set" you mean "non-leaf node set".

Clearly, there's no way to tell just by looking at an XPath whether it will select leaf nodes, non-leaf nodes, both, or nothing at all, but you can do this:

Do two XPath selections, one for (*TheOriginalXPath*) + `[*]`, and the other for (*TheOriginalXPath*) + `[not(*)]`, so:

```
/OrderResponse/OrderLine[2]/LineItem/ID[*]
```

and

```
/OrderResponse/OrderLine[2]/LineItem/ID[not(*)]
```

- If only the first query returns results, then the nodes are non-leaf elements
- If only the second query returns results, then the nodes are leaf nodes
- If both return results, then the XPath matches a mixture of leaf nodes and non-leaf elements
- If neither returns results, then the XPath doesn't match anything

Comment: This is exactly what I expected.. Thanks a lot for helping me out!